# How do I parse an error message of API request in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, api, parsing, moltin

I am looking to retrieve the 'detail' part of the error so I can present an alert to the user telling them the error. How do I parse the error message and get the 'detail' section?

```
responseError(underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=com.moltin Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={errors=(
        {
        detail = "You cannot check out with an empty cart";
        status = 400;
        title = "Bad Request";
    }
)}))
```

The API call looks something like this:

```
func retrieveCartItems() {
        moltin.cart.items(forCartID: "userCart") { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                self.cartArray = response.data!
                for item in self.cartArray {
                    let divisor = Double(item.unitPrice.amount)*Double(item.quantity)/100
                    self.priceArray.append(divisor)
                    let displayPrice = String(format: "£%.02f", divisor)
                    self.displayPriceArray.append(displayPrice)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.calculateTotalPrice()
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Got failure: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error always has a consistent format like you posted. You can get error detail like this:

```
let errorDetail = ((error as NSError).userInfo["errors"] as? [[String: Any]])?.first?["detail"] as? String
```

Comment: when I try to unwrap error as NSError and print the result, the 'userInfo' section disappears and I'm not sure why (it looks like this: Error Domain=moltin.MoltinError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.moltin error 400.))